# Writing a custom input manipulator

Tags: c++, istream, streambuf, manipulators

I need to make a custom istream manipulator that reads 5 characters from input, then skip 5 characters from input, and does it to the end of the string. Example:

```
string line;
cin >> skipchar >> line;
```

This is that I did, but it doesn't work for some reason. Also, it would be better, if I don't use `<sstream>`

```
struct membuf : streambuf
{
    membuf(char* begin, char* end) {
        this->setg(begin, begin, end);
    }
};
istream& skipchar(istream& stream)
{
    string temp;
    getline(stream, temp);
    char *str = new char[temp.size() + 1];
    strcpy(str, temp.c_str());//get string and convert to char*

    char* res = new char[strlen(str)];
    for (int i=0,j=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
        if ((i / 5) % 2 == 0) //get first 5, then 5 skip, etc
            res[j++] = str[i];

    membuf b(res, res + strlen(res)); //copy str to buffer
    stream.rdbuf(&b);
    return stream;
}
int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "enter smth:\n";
    cin >> skipchar >> str;
    cout << "entered string: " << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show your input, but I don't think `getline()` would be appropriate to use in this situation. `operator>>` is meant to read a single word, not a whole line.

In any case, you are leaking both `char[]` arrays that you allocate.  You need to `delete[]` them when you are done using them.  For the `str` array (which FYI, you don't actually need, as you could just copy characters from the `temp` string directly into `res` instead), you can just `delete[]` it before exiting. But for `res`, the `membuf` would have to hold on to that pointer and `delete[]` it when the `membuf` itself is no longer being used.

But, more importantly, your use of `membuf` is simply wrong. You are creating it as a local variable of `skipchar()`, so it will be destroyed when `skipchar()` exits, leaving the `stream` with a *dangling pointer* to an invalid object.  The `streambuf*` pointer you assign to the `stream` must remain valid for the entire duration that it is assigned to the `istream`, which means creating the `membuf` object with `new`, and then the caller will have to remember to manually `delete` it at a later time (which kind of defeats the purpose of using `operator>>`).  However, a stream manipulator really should not change the `rdbuf` that the `stream` is pointing at in the first place, since there is not a good way to restore the previous `streambuf` after subsequent read operations are finished (unless you define another manipulator to handle that, ie `cin >> skipchar >> str >> stopskipchar;`).

In this situation, I would suggest a different approach.  Don't make a stream manipulator that assigns a new `streambuf` to the `stream`, thus affecting all subsequent `operator>>` calls.  Instead, make a manipulator that takes a reference to the output variable, and then reads from the `stream` and outputs only what is needed (similar to how standard manipulators like [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) and [`std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) work), eg:

```
struct skipchars
{
    string &str;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& stream, skipchars output)
{
    string temp;
    if (stream >> temp) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < temp.size(); i += 10) {
            output.str += temp.substr(i, 5);
        }
    }
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "enter smth:\n";
    cin >> skipchars{str};
    cout << "entered string: " << str;
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/31Zx7K)

Alternatively:

```
struct skipcharsHelper
{
    string &str;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& stream, skipcharsHelper output)
{
    string temp;
    if (stream >> temp) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < temp.size(); i += 10) {
            output.str += temp.substr(i, 5);
        }
    }
    return stream;
}

skipcharsHelper skipchars(string &str)
{
    return skipcharsHelper{str};
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "enter smth:\n";
    cin >> skipchars(str);
    cout << "entered string: " << str;
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/j7YlWY)

Comment: Thanks! But I need to use a manipulator in code and input should be like this: 
cin >> skipchar >> line;
 That is why I started to use streams and membuf.

Comment: "*input should be like this: `cin >> skipchar >> line;`*" - sorry, but there is no safe way to implement that syntax the way you want (that I know of, anyway). What is wrong with the approach I suggested? This is the way the standard library implements such manipulators, so why can't you follow the same pattern?

Comment: Your suggestion is perfect, but this is how the task was given. Well, if you say that it's the only one way of solving this problem, I will follow your suggestion. Thanks again)

Comment: "*this is how the task was given*"  - then your task is misguided. That way is not how stream manipulators are meant to be used.